# IT Hit WebDAV Server for .NET Return Custom Properties

Tags: c#, .net, webdav

I have the need to send back custom property information when users right-click on file listings served up by my WebDAV server. However, so far I cannot seem to figure out how to get them to show up.

I see the GetProperties() and GetPropertyNames() methods and how to load up a list of PropertyName objects:

```
private void loadProperties()
{
     propVals.Add(new PropertyValue(new PropertyName("ParcelID","ECMailbox"),parcel.ParcelID.ToString()));
}

public override IEnumerable<PropertyValue> GetProperties(IList<PropertyName> props, bool allprop)
{
     foreach (PropertyValue p in propVals)
     {
          if (allprop || props.Contains(p.QualifiedName))
          {
               yield return p;
          }
     }
}

public override IEnumerable<PropertyName> GetPropertyNames()
{
     return propVals.Select(p => p.QualifiedName);
}
```

I do see these being called, but nothing comes up in Explorer (Win7 64-bit). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer (with Mini-Redirector) is a WebDAV client and it will not show any information about custom properties (or Dead Properties) because it was not programmed for this. This behavior does not depend on WebDAV server you use.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different WebDAV client.

I test my service with CarotDAV and Fiddler.
CarotDAV is a free GUI application.

http://rei.to/carotdav_en.html